# Can your SSID affect connectivity?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ssid

I have google fiber at home, and with working from home lately, we've started to run into some issues.

Specifically, my wife's phone (samsung galaxy S9+) will intermittently disconnect, and my mac book pro (2019, 15") will say it's connected (and at full bars!), but have no internet access.

I have been able to temporarily fix these issues by switching between my 5GHz and my 2.4GHz network on my mac, and/or cycling the wifi on the mac. I am also able to fix the issue (again temporarily) by rebooting the wireless router (it's the default one google fiber gives). Note that speed and latency while connected are both what I'd expect, at least as reported by fast.com (about 200mbps up and down, and about 20ms latency)

We also have a dell precision 5510 laptop, a first gen surface book, and a OnePlus 6 which have had 0 issues.

My wife called up google's tech support, and they mentioned that it could be the SSID which is giving problems. I've never heard of this before, and wanted to check before I change the SSID and reconnect all our many devices. Our current SSIDs:

- 5GHz: Wi believe I can Fi
- 2.4GHz: Wi believe I can touch the sky

The tech's suggestion was to change the SSIDs to between 8-32 alphanumeric characters, no spaces or special characters.

My question to you: Does it matter? If so why? Also, should I keep the SSIDs different, or change them to be the same?

Comment: It is up to the client to succesfully handle proper SSID's, but yeah, it can lead to weird problems. I would replace spaces to _ or none (capitalize each word's first letter) and make it shorter. If both 5Ghz and 2.4 Ghz share the same name, it may lead to problems for some clients that don't support this.

Comment: But even simpler, set the wifi to a short name, test it for a few days and see if the situation changes.